How to convert datatables.net parameters to parameter string format
how to convert table.ajax.params() to string format of parameters url?
I use JQuery Datatables datatables.net
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    //... settings
});

I understand that I can get parameters with table.ajax.params(), but I want to send them for server with correct format:
draw: 1
columns[0][data]: id
columns[0][name]: 
columns[0][searchable]: true
columns[0][orderable]: true
columns[0][search][value]: 
columns[0][search][regex]: false
columns[1][data]: version
columns[1][name]: 
columns[1][searchable]: true
...

but my URL is looks like above:
http://localhost:80/api/v1/users?[object%20Object]

correct format is:
http://localhost:80/api/v1/users?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=id&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&...

Thank you for your time

The format of the data you show typically doesn't go in the URL. And even if it does, then the format would be different (using & as separators and = for the key-values). What exactly are you trying to do? Send the data in the URL, or send what format you've shown, which should go in the body? Or something different?

Hello, I want to send parameters to server with same Datatables format. This format is correct for send to server (query parameter)

I can do it. I use $.param(parameters) and set as data in ajax JQuery 
my code is:
let parameters = table.ajax.params();
let queryString = $.param(parameters);

$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'http://localhost:80/api/v1/users',
      data: queryString,
      contentType: "application/json",
      encode: true,
}).done(function (data) {
      // ....
}).fail(function (err) {
      // ....
});

